# What is the cause of "stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00" in Arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I was using Arduino Uno to build a robot, but suddenly this error 
(`stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00`)
 occurred. I tried a lot, searched on the net, to fix this error, but no solution worked for me. At last I bough 2 new Arduinos. But each of those 2 Arduinos ran few days correctly and after a few days gave the same error.

I was, and am, unable to find what causes this error. Can anyone kindly tell what could be the mistake I may be doing?

Comment: Is this intermittent, or do your Arduinos flat-out refuse to work?

Comment: @swdeveloper, have just updated my answer.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened when the COM port is not correctly selected.  Determine the COM port used to communicate with Arduino and set in in the IDE, then recompile the sketch.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the reason from this link
[of this error](http://www.parkansky.com/arduino-error.htm).

There are a TON of pages out there on how to solve this error. The problem is none of them worked for me. The typical solutions range from not having the correct serial port or correct Arduino model board selected under the Tools menu in the Arduino software, to not having a driver (or the correct driver) loaded.

However, the frustating part for me is I KNEW I had the correct serial port and board and driver selected because I was getting output from a sketch scrolling in the Serial Monitor window via a USB connection.

The fix? DISCONNECT ANY WIRES going to pin 0 (RX) while you do the upload. The sketch upload function uses the RX pin.

NOTE:   You also need to disconnect any wires going to pin 0 (RX) if you have a sketch with a Serial.read() or Serial.peek() statement, and you want to use the Serial Monitor input field (as shown using the '752' in the example below) to feed data into the running sketch. If you don't disconnect pin 0 it will appear as if your data was entered into your sketch but nothing will happen because the data never truly gets input.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like there is no connection between PC and Arduino. Possible reasons: Something wrong with USB port OR driver, USB wire, ATMega16 controller, ATMega328 UART or bootloader. First, try to check, if data from Serial Port reaches Arduino. Pull ATMEGA from socket, short-circuit pins RX and TX on Arduino board (pins 0 and 1), and send some data from PC. You should receive exactly same string, as you sent. Also you should se RX TX LED's blinking. If you can't see data back, check if serial port you are using are actually exist in device manager, try to play with it's settings (speed, port numer), try to use another USB port and cable, etc.

Comment: I have tried all these solutions, but none of these has worked for me

Comment: You mean, you didn't seen any response, even then RX-TX was shorted? Does serial port apears then you plug USB in your Arduino board?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. But for me no led was lighting up on connection and the error observed was the same as yours. I fixed this by changing jumper pin configuration from `ext to usb` . You can try the same settings by altering the `jumper pins between power jack and usb jack`.